# 1998 Toyota Camry brake caliper/caliper bracket mismatch

Tags: toyota, brakes, camry, brake-calipers

I have a 1998 Toyota Camry and trying to fix the front brakes. I found the driver's side front caliper to be bad (won't compress). I pulled a caliper off another 1998 Camry and it won't fit the bracket I have (the screw holes are about a 1/4 inch farther apart on this caliper). I then pulled the bracket from the other Camry, and that bracket won't fit my car (again, the screw holes don't line up).

Why would the driver's side front caliper and bracket be different between 2 identical 1998 Camry's? How do I shop for another caliper not knowing whether it will fit the bracket that fits my car? Any insight and recommendations would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

If one of the vehicles was a V6 and the other is a 4-cyl, they have different parts numbers, so they are different parts, to include the brackets. More than likely the V6 has a larger diameter rotor, so has a different sized caliper and caliper bracket. Any which way, it will be different. It would be the only explanation I have for you.